# Improve range on a differential ADC

Tags: adc, differential, voltage-reference

I'm using an [MCP3425](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22072b.pdf) ADC, it has differential inputs but I'm using it as single ended mode.

The signal that I want to digitize comes from an integrator circuit (an op amp with a capacitor in its feedback loop).The signal is basically a ramp that lasts 2 seconds and goes from 0V to up to 3.3V.

Given that this ADC can not measure signals of voltages greater than its reference of 2.048V. And I want to use the full range of my signal, is it OK if I improve it's range by driving the non-inverting input with an 1.25V voltage reference and the inverting input with my signal?

Because 1.25V + 2.048V = 3.298V, when the ramps is 3.3V the diferential voltage will be of 2,048V.

I have already tried this circuit and I know It works, what I want to know is if this approach does not hinder circuit performance in any other aspect. (e.g.: bandwidth, noise, EMI, etc)

Below is a simplified schematic of my circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkhi30.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: I forgot to add that I want to improve range without sacrificing resolution, that is why the is no atenuation stage between integrator and ADC.

Comment: Why not 1.65V? Then you don't clip at the 3.3V peak.

Comment: You wouldn't need to add a voltage reference on the second stage if you add attenuation resistors to the first stage.

Comment: That's a valid suggestion, I haven't thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: But the better solution is to reconfigure your first stage to have a differential layout.

Comment: @Reinderien I wan't to improve range without sacrificing resolution. I should edit my question accordingly.